# How to create when i click 1st item in arrayList1 will open page with 1st item in arrayList2

Tags: android-studio

When I click first or second item from 1st array list I get first item from array list two, but I need if i click second item on array list 1 I get shown second item from list two

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<String> 1stArrayList;
    ArrayList<String> 2ndArrayList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        1stArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        1stArrayList .add("A");
        1stArrayList .add("B");
        1stArrayList .add("C");

        2ndArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        2ndArrayList.add("1");
        2ndArrayList.add("2");
        2ndArrayList.add("3");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.item, 1stArrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                String 2ndArrayList= listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.putString("2ndArrayList ", 2ndArrayList );
                editor.apply();

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ThirdActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more your problem? From what i understand, the problem is that you're receiving the same item (first) from `2ndArrayList` when clicking on different views from the listview, is that right?  
Also, be careful with the aliasing of 2ndArrayList at `String 2ndArrayList= listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();`. It's in an anonymous class, so i don't believe it will clash with your array name in `SecondActivity`, but it might confuse you later.

Comment: you understand right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution would be getting the value directly from the array using the position of the view clicked. Like the following:

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            String secListItem = secArrayList.get(position);
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("2ndArrayList", secListItem );
            editor.apply();

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ThirdActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

But you have to be sure that both the arrays will have the same size or you may have an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Another solution would be using some Map with the values from arraylist1 and arraylist2, implementing a custom adapter that extends BaseAdapter, populating the views with the values from the first array with getView() and using getItem() to return the values from the second list, but that's harder to do.

Also if you don't mean to persist the item and only transfer them between activities, you can use the `Intent` to do it. In this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ThirdActivity.class);
Intent.putExtra("2ndArrayList", secListItem);
startActivity(intent);
```

And recover in the third activity with something like:

```
String secArrayItem = "";
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) secArrayItem = extras.getString("2ndArrayList");
```